# MultiValueDictKeyError at /account/register

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, web-development-server

Error:
MultiValueDictKeyError at /account/register
'first_name'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/register
Django Version: 2.2.7
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:
'first_name'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Maansi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in **getitem**, line 80
views.py:

```
 def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            messages.info(request,'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request,"login.html")

def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        username=request.POST['username']
        password1=request.POST['password1']
        password2=request.POST['password2']
        email=request.POST['email']
        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request,'Email Taken')
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request,'Username Taken')
                return redirect('register')
            else:    
             user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password1,email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
                user.save()
                print('user created')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request,"Password don't match!")
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        return render(request,"register.html")
```

login.html

```
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input class="form-control valid" name="username" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your username'" placeholder="Enter your username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input class="form-control valid" name="password" id="password" type="password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Password'" placeholder="Enter Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

register.html:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="register" method="post">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="first_name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" placeholder="Enter your name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="last_name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your last name'" placeholder="Enter your last name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="username" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your username'" placeholder="Enter your username">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="password1" id="password" type="password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Create Password'" placeholder="Create Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="password2" id="password" type="password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Confirm Password'" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/register

Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['news.apps.NewsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Maansi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  78.             list_ = super().__getitem__(key)

During handling of the above exception ('first_name'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\Maansi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Maansi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Maansi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Maansi\projects\Learn\account\views.py" in register
  34.         first_name=request.GET['first_name']

File "C:\Users\Maansi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  80.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /account/register
Exception Value: 'first_name'
```

What is the problem with first_name. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: The error means that it can not find the key in `request.POST`, for example if it errors on `request.POST['username']`, then `username` is not a key in the POST headers.

Comment: What does that means? I am currently new to django

Comment: Where is `first_name=request.GET['first_name']` defined in your code?

Comment: @Hybrid why would you need that? you have to get it from POST headers as the request type is `post`.

Comment: @Jeet because according to the stack trace that is what is causing the error (see second to last trace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because it can not find the key `first_name` in `request.POST`.

In `Python`, dictionaries have a build-in static method `.get()`. When `.get()` can't find the key, it returns `None` by default or the value you specified.

My suggestion is to use `.get()`. Here is the example-

Change

```
first_name=request.POST["first_name"]
```

to

```
first_name=request.POST.get("first_name", "default value")
```

Also, there is no need to write `{% csrf_token %}` before every input field. Only one `csrf_token` is required per form. So you can remove the other ones just keep one inside the form tag.

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace of type error?

Comment: Or atleast provide where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot Jeet!! It solved my problem...I was not adding up any default value which gave that type error, now it's solved. This error had got me stuck for many hours.

Answer (score 0):

check the fistname field of your register.html and make sure firstname input field must have a name of first_name.


For example
`<input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" required>`